# Unexpected token '=' Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am having a problem with Javascript, I keep getting the unexpected token error '=' when trying to run my script. I have done some digging around and the way the default parameters are declared in this way is new to ES6. I am using "use strict", which is what I assumed was the way to use the latest Javascript features. But I am still getting this error when trying to use default parameters, does anyone know why?
Here is my code:

```
    // rectangle sprite
    "use strict";
// creates canvas
let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.setAttribute("width", "500");
canvas.setAttribute("height", "500");
canvas.style.border = "1px dashed black";
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let rectangle = function(   
    //Define the function's parameters with their default values
    width = 32,
    height = 32,
    fillStyle = "gray",
    strokeStyle = "none",
    lineWidth = 0,
    x = 0,
    y = 0
    ) {
    //Create an object called `o` (the lowercase letter "o")
    //that is going to be returned by this
    //function. Assign the function's arguments to it
    let o = {width, height, fillStyle, strokeStyle, lineWidth, x, y};
    //Add optional rotation, alpha, visible, and scale properties
    o.rotation = 0;
    o.alpha = 1;
    o.visible = true;
    o.scaleX = 1;
    o.scaleY = 1;
    //Add `vx` and `vy` (velocity) variables that will help us move the sprite
    o.vx = 0;
    o.vy = 0;
    //Add a `render` method that explains how to draw the sprite
    o.render = ctx => {
    ctx.strokeStyle = o.strokeStyle;
    ctx.lineWidth = o.lineWidth;
    ctx.fillStyle = o.fillStyle;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(-o.width / 2, -o.height / 2, o.width, o.height);
    if (o.strokeStyle !== "none") ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
    };
    //Push the sprite object into the `children` array
    children.push(o);
    //Return the object
    return o;
};
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: What line gives you that error?

Comment: Works for me on FireFox 44.0.2

Comment: _I am using "use strict", which is what I assumed was the way to use the latest Javascript features._ - nope, "use strict" not related to browser implementation ES6 feature

Comment: `"use strict"` is not designed as a way to enable ES6 features. If your JavaScript compiler is throwing that error, then it simply doesn't support that feature. You haven't told us what compiler you are using though.

Comment: in what browser you try it?

Comment: Sorry should have stated that, its the line with 'width = 32'

Comment: using chrome, I guess im wrong about use strict then

Comment: you think it could be a chrome issue?

Comment: [Basic support in Chrome: from 49 version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @adeneo granted the indentation is horrible, but you are looking at [default function parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters) actually. `let rect = function(width = 32, height = 32, etc)`

Comment: I have tried using ';' and using var in front of each variable but still getting the same error. Except the error says that the word 'var' is now the problem

Comment: @RogierSpieker - I just noticed, didn't see the missing `)` which makes those "variables" actually arguments

Comment: @user3355961, check version your browser, this feature in chrome available from 49 version. and from 15 in firefox, in another browser - not supported

Comment: If using Chrome, checking the version isn't neccessary, Chrome 49 will be released at the end of this month

Comment: It looks like this doesnt work in chrome then. Thanks though guys, i will use Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Default values are only supported in chrome 49 which is not still available.

Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility

Comment: chrome 49 is available

Comment: Well, not on archlinux then @guest271314

Comment: _"Well, not on archlinux then" See_ https://download-chromium.appspot.com/ ; should be over version 50 now

Comment: He said he was on chrome and not on a nightly release. https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/google-chrome/

Comment: Im going to switch to firefox, thanks for the help though guys.

Comment: Even on chrome can set launch `flag` to `--javascript-harmony`. fwiw, chrome is chromium with a branding